# typo3 add script into the head section

Tags: typo3

As I am a new at TYPO3 I would like to ask for some help.
I have problems with adding scripts into the website, so could you tell how I can add script into the head section of the website. 
Another thing that I would like to ask is how to create a new page and insert a script into it, but this script to be added only on that specific page. 
The last thing that I would like to know is how to add and an iframe (video for example).
 Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [ask].
If you got a specific problem with code you wrote you can feel free to ask here, but you are asking on tutorials & answers you could easily find on google. This is off-topic here, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

Answer (score 0):

Thats a job for Typoscript!

**How to add js scripts to any page (header)**

```
page.includeJS.identifier = EXT:your_ext_key/Resources/Public/JavaScript/filename.js
```

**How to add js script to a specific page (header)**

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id=1234]
page.includeJS.identifier = EXT:your_ext_key/Resources/Public/JavaScript/filename.js
[global]
```

You *can* modify the "identifier" name. It can be alphanumeric.

Put that typoscript either to the root page of your page in a Typoscript Template element from the backend, or have it sourced from another file.

See the [typoscript docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/) for more input.